# PHP/mysql: how do I display records sorted by time and grouped by date?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I need to display records grouped by date, and sorted by time. In the mysql table I have a field called `entry_time` which has php `time()` values stored in it. Any ideas what would be the most compact and simplest way to do this?

Ex: I need a display like:

```
21st April
3:00 pm
3:50 pm

22 April
5:00 am
4:00 pm
```

Comment: maybe you show your SQL query?

Comment: how does your table look like? do you have date and time stored seperately?

Comment: I am asking for the sql query...

And as I said, my table has a `timestamp` field that stores timestamps during entry_time

`id(int,primary),entry_time(timestamp)`

Comment: then table structure would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough half-pseudo code:

```
$records = /* SELECT * FROM `records` ORDER BY `entry_time` */;

$date = null;
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $currentDate = date('Ymd', $record['entry_time']);
    if ($currentDate != $date) {
        printf('<h1>%s</h1>', date('Y-m-d', $record['entry_time']));
    }
    $date = $currentDate;

    echo date('H:i', $record['entry_time']);
}
```

Comment: You have forgot else statement.

Comment: What do I need an `else` for here?

Comment: Why not put the `$date = $currentDate;` call within the if? Saves you some assignments and you only need to change `$date` if `$currentDate != $date`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're processing the query results with PHP, consider writing a simple query to sort your records by date:

```
SELECT NameOfMyThing, MyDateField FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyDateField DESC
```

Then use PHP to read the results:

```
$last_day = '';
while ($row = $query_result->fetch()) {
    $date = new DateTime($row->['MyDateField']);

    $day = $date->format('j F');     // '9 April'
    $time = $date->format('g:i a');  // '9:05 am'

    if ($day != $last_day) {
        print $day . "\n";
        $last_day = $day;
    }

    print $time . " " . $row->['NameOfMyThing'];
}
```

The idea here is to remember the last day you saw, and only output the date when the day changes.

(Code untested, optimized for readability only).

Answer (score 0):

Have a multidimensional array.

```
$datetime = array("April 21st" => array("5:00a.m", "4:00p.m"), "April 22nd" => array(...));
```

Then you can sort based on date and time separately.

Comment: Personally I would do the query one row at a time, and while data is returned from that row build the array. You could do a sort of insertion sort, or you could sort the array after you're finished building it. I did not attempt to write a query because if the date is all in one field, I'm unaware of any method to only sort by "parts" of the field.

Comment: You'd really do the query one row at a time? Let's say there is a year's worth of data, 3 entries per day. That's over 1,000 queries you'll be hitting against the database. Add to which, you'll be then using PHP's sort() after the fact, doing string comparison no less. Sorry but I think this is a recipe for a severe bottleneck.

Comment: No sorry, not one row at a time. Do mysql_query, then do while(mysql_fetch_row ... !== false) (extreme pseudo-code, and I wouldn't use the built-in functions but I can't remember the PDO stuff)

Answer (score 0):

When you have `time()` stored in database, the easiest way is to:

1. Sort table by column with `time()`.
2. Query for every record's timestamp from table (I assume that you only want dates and times).
3. For each row in result, call `date()` twice: once for day and month, one for hour. Have last used date saved and if they are same, put next time to same array element as prievous (I am assuming that you use LainIwakura's solution of storing such data).
4. Display it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

An sql query like this (using wordpress as an example) would get you the records in the correct order, and have the correct formatting:

```
select date_format(post_date, "%d %b")  as day, date_format(post_date, "%T") as time from wp_posts;
```

You could then iterate through this array and start a new "day" heading whenever the first column changes.

I really wouldn't recommend querying the db one row at a time as suggested by @Lainlwakura's comment - PHP is slow, iterating over single row queries is slow. PHP array sorting, especially on string keys is incredible slow. If you are listing records spanning a year or so, that approach won't work.

Let mysql do as much for you as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I might be thinking way too easy, but guess it could be done with:

```
SELECT DATE(`datefield`) `date`, TIME(`datefield`) `time` FROM `yourtable` ORDER BY `datefield` ASC;
```

And then just show it with PHP. MySQL is just for fetching the data, not for displaying it. :)

Answer (score 0):

query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( entry_time, '%D %M' ) as date,
       GROUP_CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( entry_time, '%h:%i %p' )
                     ORDER BY entry_time ASC
                     SEPARATOR '<br />' ) as times
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DATE( entry_time )
ORDER BY entry_time
```

results in:

```
> date        times

> 21st April  3:00 PM<br />3:50 PM

> 22st April  5:00 AM<br />4:00 PM
```

then you can go through it:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
   echo $row->date. '<br />'. $row->times. '<br />';
}
```

**edit:**
the benefit is that all sorting & formatting is done in mysql engine, so you have a ready to display result

**edit2:**
That query will give you exactly result you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( entry_time, '%D %M' ), "<br />\n",
               GROUP_CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( entry_time, '%h:%i %p' )
                             ORDER BY entry_time ASC
                             SEPARATOR '<br />' ), "<br /><br />\n"
       ) as dates
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DATE( entry_time )
ORDER BY entry_time
```

use *foreach* (or any other array func.) to go through it:

`foreach($result as $row) { echo $row->dates; }`